# Structural find/replace in Resharper format identifier

Tags: resharper, structural-search

When using R# structural find/replace, is it then possible to alter/modify the output of a token?

e.g. if I capture an identifier, can I then reformat this using regex in the output?
I'd like to transform this:

`[Fact]
public void SomeMethodName()`

with:

`[Fact(DisplayName = "Some method name"]
public void SomeMethodName()`

Possible?

Answer (score 0):

Structural Search and Replace doesn't support anything like this - i.e. something like Live Template's macros. It would be very nice if it did! Here's a YouTrack feature request that you can vote on and track: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-166388